# delete empty space borders in dhtmlxLayout web skin

Tags: layout, border, dhtmlx

How to delete empty space borders from dhtmlxLayout web skin, to make it similar to skyblue skin?

```
document.getElementsByClassName(" dhxtabbar_base_dhx_web")[0].style.margin = 0;
```

doesn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
.dhxlayout_base_dhx_web div.dhx_cell_layout div.dhx_cell_cont_layout {
padding: 0;
}
```